# Environment expansion in R

Tags: r, environment

I have some problem I don't know how to solve.
Prehistory: I use R.NET for my calculation (need WPF application). So, I want to parallelize my app, and I created dynamic proxy for REngine class. It needs to serialize data to pass and receive data from-to REngine instance via TCP. Bad news - R.NET classes cannot be serialized. So, I have an idea to serialize R objects in R and pass R serialized data between processes.

So I have same script like this:

```
a <- 5;
b <- 10;
x <- a+b;
```

I need to wrap it like this:

```
wrapFunction <- function()
{
    a <- 5;
    b <- 10;
    x <- a+b;
}

serializedResult <- serialize(wrapFunction());
```

I'll get serializedResult and pass it as byte array. Also I need to pass environments. But I won't get a, b, x in .GlobalEnv after these manipulations. 
How is it possible to get all variables, defined in function body, in my .GlobalEnv? 
I don't know names and count, I can't rewrite basic script, replacing "<-" by "<<-".
Other ways?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements. They seem to go against the functional language paradigm, which R tries to follow. The following might be helpful or not:

```
e <- new.env()
wrapFunction <- function(){
  with(e, {
         a <- 5;
         b <- 10;
         x <- a+b;
          })
}

wrapFunction()
e$a
#[1] 5
```

You can of course use the `.GlobalEnv` instead of `e`, but at least in R that would be considered an even worse practice.

Comment: Great! Thank you! It works! That's I need! 

<code>       
e <- new.env();

formalFunctionWrapper <- function(envir = parent.env())
{
 with(e, {
   tstFunction <- function(a)
   {
    tstFunction <- a^3;
   }

   b <- tstFunction(6);
   c <- b+5;
    });

 #for(v in ls()) 
 #{
 # assign(v, newEnv[[v]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
 #}
}

c1 <- formalFunctionWrapper();
e$b

for(v in ls(e)) 
{
 assign(v, e[[v]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

ls(globalenv())

</code>

Comment: Why copy into the global envronment as a subsequent step? You can just do `with(.GlobalEnv, ...)`.

Comment: Emmmm... You wrote: " but at least in R that would be considered an even worse practice". I always use advices I received from guru. ))

Comment: Well, what I meant was that you shouldn't assign local variables into the global environment. If you still decide to do that, you can do it directly.

Comment: Ahhh, understood. ))) Thank you again!